# Pyglet hello world example doesn't show label until a key is pressed

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pyglet

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()
label = pyglet.text.Label("Hello World!",
                            font_name="Times New Roman",
                            color=(255,255,255,255),
                            font_size=36,
                            x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                            anchor_x="center", anchor_y="center")

@window.event
def on_draw():
     window.clear()
     label.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

This code is taken from the pyglet tutorial at https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/quickstart.html but when run it doesn't draw the label until any key is pressed. I added the color as I thought the text may have defaulted to black.

Am I missing something really obvious as to why this behaviour is happening?

OK, having had my memory jogged by the comments, I installed the MS Fonts and it now works in python 2.x but I still need to press a key to see the text in python 3. Maybe the font thing is a red-herring and there is some incompatibility with python 3.

Comment: Are you 100% positive that this is the code you're running? Because this code works as intended on my setup https://youtu.be/Yc_25-CxAak -- Versions Python: 3.5.1 / Pyglet: 1.2.2

Comment: You've tagged this question with "Ubuntu" even tho you're trying to load pyglet with "Times New Roman", was this on purpose? Because TNR doesn't excist on Linux by default.

Comment: Technically Kubuntu but it turns out I had forgotten to install the Microsoft fonts. I knew it would be a simple thing.

Comment: Oh, I just realized you forgot to call `.flip()`, I'll update my answer in a sec.

Comment: I'm very interested in seeing if `.flip()` solved the issue, if that's the case then the documentation isn't correct. I've never witnessed the problem myself, but I've seen a bunch of others having this issue. Perhaps it's driver related.. But I'd still like to know : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments.
Most examples found on the internet (even most guides) assume a Windows platform.

If there's a `font=` declaration with a Windows font but you're running Linux, make sure you got the proper fonts installed or revert to a font you've got installed.

```
$ fc-list
```

Also not declaring a font will work too:

```
label = pyglet.text.Label("Hello World!",
                            color=(255,255,255,255),
                            font_size=36,
                            x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                            anchor_x="center", anchor_y="center")
```

Because Pyglet will default to sans-serif:

> If you do not particularly care which font is used, and just need to display some readable text, you can specify None as the family name, which will load a default sans-serif font (Helvetica on Mac OS X, Arial on Windows XP)

Your issue is probably that you don't manually update the screen after you drew something. Normally when you press a key, it forces a `window.flip()`, which basically means update the screen content.
`window.clear()` also triggers this behavior, but `x.draw()` does not. Why? Well the thing that takes time in computer graphics is not really the calculations, it's the updating them to the screen that takes time.. There for `.draw()` doesn't update the screen, it just puts the stuff in the graphical buffer ("page"), you decide when to flip the page and show the new buffer on the screen.

Try this out:

```
@window.event
def on_draw():
        window.clear()
        label.draw()
        window.flip()
```

This might be a overkill solution, but it will probably solve the problem.
This overrides the default loop of pyglet and the default draw behavior, it's also one of the classes i use the most in my pyglet projects since it gives me the option to create my own framework.

```
import pyglet

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__(vsync = False)
        self.sprites = {}
        self.sprites['testlabel'] = label = pyglet.text.Label("Hello World!",
                        color=(255,255,255,255),
                        font_size=36,
                        x=self.width//2, y=self.height//2, #self here, being pyglet.window.Window that we've inherited and instanciated with super().
                        anchor_x="center", anchor_y="center")
        self.alive = 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        for sprite_name, sprite_obj in self.sprites.items():
            sprite_obj.draw()
        self.flip()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            self.render()
            # This is very important, this queries (and empties)
            # the pyglet event queue, if this queue isn't cleared
            # pyglet will hang because it can't input more events,
            # and a full buffer is a bad buffer, so we **NEED** this!
            event = self.dispatch_events()

win = Window()
win.run()
```

It's extremely basic, but you can add more sprites, objects and render them in `def render(self):`.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Thank you. There is a typo in your code:

`sprite.obj.draw()` should be `sprite_obj_draw()` other than that it works brilliantly.

Adding the flip() in the original code didn't work until I changed `window = pyglet.window.Window()` to `window = pyglet.window.Window(vsync = False)`

Comment: @Elija Perfect, changed my code to `sprite_obj.draw()`. Thank you for pointing it out! Regarding the `vsync = False` thing, that's a good point. I will experiment with it and see if I can update the official documentation if it turns out that works better with the general population. I'll also change so that a specific font isn't defined in the first Hello World example since it may cause some issues with cross-platform users apparently.

Comment: Hmm, neither `.flip()` or `vsync = False` worked for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Pakman depends, what happens? have you installed all the drivers that you're supposed to? does any other graphical application work? Have you copied the exact code? did you name it `pyglet.py` and now nothing works?

Comment: Hey @Torxed, thanks for the quick response. I'm using Arch linux on a Dell 9550 with 960M/Intel 530HD, but I've disabled the Nvidia card and I'm only using Intel for display (xf86-video-intel). I copied the example and tried both not specifying `font_name` and explicitly setting it to `None`, but each time, the text will only display after I press a button on the keyboard. My file is _not_ named pyglet ;).

Comment: The same example worked on Windows. I should note that my WM is Qtile. Would that affect things? I can't tell if it's reparenting or not, but I've hit [issues](https://github.com/swaywm/sway/issues/595) with that in the past

Comment: @Pakman Have you installed `mesa`? which enables 3D acceleration. Yea I have no idea but I would say running anything graphical in a virtual environment might cause issues. Because there might be optimizations that puts the machine to "sleep" while nothing is actively updating the graphical buffer in the machine.

Comment: @Torxed, turns out Qtile _was_ the culprit, but not because it may or may not be reparenting. The example works fine in both DWM (non-reparenting) and StumpWM (reparenting) window managers.