# Pyglet label text not displaying in python 3.9

Tags: python, pyglet

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L2cM.jpg)
Tried same code in 3.7 and the label can be displayed but not in python 3.9

I tried run same code in 3.7 and the label can be displayed.

Version of pyglet is 1.5.16.

Tried to add "win.flip()" but still no luck.

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.text
window = pyglet.window.Window(500,500, "Testing!!!")
label = pyglet.text.Label("Hello,wold!!!",x=10,y=10)
label.color = (100, 255, 100, 255)

@window.event
def on_draw():   
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
    window.flip()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Can you show the code? (a minimum reproducable example) and say exactly what you mean by "doesn't work" (full traceback, or description if there is no error)

Comment: Posted code. No error showed. Just got blank Window. The title can be displayed.

Comment: If you remove `window.flip()` it works fine for me. The text appears in the bottom left corner

Comment: What is your python version?I tried in 3.7 and the text can be displayed too but not in 3.9.Actually I didn't put window.flip() in my first try. I just tried to remove it but still same. I just follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354309/pyglet-hello-world-example-doesnt-show-label-until-a-key-is-pressed

Comment: I'm running python 3.9.4 and pyglet 1.5.16. Can you post a screenshot of what your window looks like if you remove `window.flip()`

Comment: Posted Output.,,,,

Comment: In my case also removing the window.flip() results in the label being drawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.
I tried to run same code in another computer with same version of Python (3.9.5) and Pyglet (1.5.16) and the label text can be displayed, so I pretty sure that the problem does not relate to both items.

Thanks for below link to give me hint that the issue maybe relate to hardware setting.
[Blank screen when running pyglet from wine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144381/blank-screen-when-running-pyglet-from-wine)

I am running the problematic code on VM in ESXi, after enable 3D support. The text can be displayed.